# Node fs showing that file is not directory when it is

Tags: node.js

I have the following code...

```
  console.log("looking for "+ path+" "+fs.lstatSync(path).isDirectory());
```

with path == "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" I get

> looking for /Volumes/Macintosh HD false

I also tried converting to "/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD" but then it can't even find the file.

Why is this not showing up as a directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `/Volumes/Macintosh HD` is actually a symlink to `/`. It's not actually a directory.

You can do this instead:

```
console.log("looking for "+ path+" symlink: "+fs.lstatSync(path).isSymbolicLink());
// outputs: looking for /Volumes/Macintosh HD symlink: true
```

If you wanted to integrate this in your logic to check to see if the symlink is pointing to a directory, you can try something like this:

```
var path = '/Volumes/Macintosh HD';

if (fs.lstatSync(path).isSymbolicLink()) {
  // replace 'path' with the real path if it's a symlink
  path = fs.readlinkSync(path);
}

if (fs.lstatSync(path).isDirectory()) {
  console.log('it is a directory!');
}
```

Comment: So one other question then, how do I tell if it is a sybmolic like to a folder or file? Is that even a concern?

Comment: @Jackie I've updated my answer with the code to do that. It is a concern if you wanted to, say, write a file to the directory. You can't do that unless you know it's actually a directory.